# Stochastic matching with fewer queries

Tags: matching, random-graphs

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and a probability $p \in [0,1]$ with which each edge is sampled from the graph $G$. The goal of the stochastic matching problem with fewer queries is to find a subgraph $H \subseteq G$ of fewer* edges such that we maximize the following ratio

A realization of a graph $G = (V,E)$ with a parameter $p \in [0,1]$ is a $G' = (V',E')$ where $V' =V$ and $E'$ is formed by sampling each edge of $E$ independently with probability $p$ i.e, $E' \subseteq E$.

$\max{ \frac{\mathbb{E}[\text{Maximum matching in the realized matching of } H]}{\mathbb{E}
[\text{Maximum matching in the realized matching of } G]} }$

A naive algorithm is to query for all the edges i.e, $H=G$. The ratio would then be $1$, however when the graph is dense the number of edges queried would be $\mathcal{O}({n^2})$.

An another naive algorithm is to query a sparse graph $H= M(G)$ where $M(G)$ is the maximum matching of $G$, I would like to understand the approximation factor for this case.
Clearly the numerator is $kp $ where $k$ is the size of maximum matching. I am unsure how to compute the denominator.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *realized matching*? It seems that you mean a random subgraph obtained by retaining each edge with probability $p$.

Comment: Edited the question. Realized matching - is the matching on the realization of the graph $G$ with parameter $p$

Comment: I still don't understand what a "realization of a graph $G$" is, or what a "realized matching" is.  I don't understand how I'm supposed to interpret the display equation with the $\max$ of the ratio.  I don't understand what it means to "query" an edge.  Some sentences seem like they might be out of order.  You seem to be looking for an algorithm to solve some task, but I can't tell what task you want solved.  What is the input to the algorithm?  What do you want its output to be?  Perhaps it would help to tell us the motivation and/or context behind this question.